# c lineal draw in a console

Tags: c, console, console-application

I'm trying to draw a lineal in my console in c.

I have a recursive programm:

```
void mark(int m, int h) {
  printf("set a mark at %d of length %d\n",m,h);
}

void ruler(int l, int r, int h) {
  int m = (l+r)/2;
  if (h>0) {
    mark(m, h);
    ruler(l, m, h-1);
    ruler(m, r, h-1);
  }
}
```

And I have to draw a lineal:

[image]

My problem is that I have the first line mark(4,3) (the central line), then I have to put another line, but I have 2 lines, the two other in each middle.

Anybody knows hows to do that? Or how can I transform this to a non recursive algorithm?

Thanks 
Best regards

Comment: Can  you give an example of what you expecting to get?  I'm confused by the phrase "...then I have to put another line."  Your recursive program, assuming that the `mark` function works correctly, should draw the center line, divide the ruler in half and put a center line in each half and so on.

Comment: If I'm reading this right: as-is this prints "set a mark at 4 of length 3;
at 2 of length 2;
at 1 of length 1;
at 3 of length 1;
at 6 of length 2;
at 5 of length 1;
at 7 of length 1;", but you want to print the lines of length 3 first, then the lines of length 2, then the lines of length 1?

Comment: You're right, problem is that, I have to print all the lines of length 2, but the program give me also lines of 1 between lines of 2!

Comment: Suggest re-ordering using `ruler(l, m, h-1); mark(m, h); ruler(m, r, h-1);` to do work in an ascending fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the segment [0, 1] on the real number line, and evaluating **ruler**(0, 1, *n*):

- **Step 1**: First you place a marker of length *n* halfway, at 1/2, splitting the segment in half
- **Step 2**: Then you place two markers of length *n*-1 in the middle of each half: at 1/4 and 3/4.
- **Step 3**: Then you place four markers of length *n*-2 at: 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8.
- **Step 4**: Then you place eight markers of length *n*-3 at: 1/16, 3/16, 5/16, ... 15/16.

...

- **Step n**: Finally, you place 2<sup>n-1</sup> markers of length 1 at: 1/2<sup>n</sup>, 3/2<sup>n</sup>, 5/2<sup>n</sup>, ...(2<sup>n</sup>-1)/2<sup>n</sup>.

For **ruler**(*l*, *r*, *n*), these fractions will be the same, but instead of, say, 3/4, you will put the marker three fourths of the way between *a* and *b*. This is simply: *l* + (*r* - *l*) * 3/4.

Translating this approach into C code, we can write your function non-recursively as:

```
void ruler(int l, int r, int n) {
    int step, num, denom;
    for (step = 1; step <= n; step++) {
        denom = 1 << step;
        for (num = 1; num < denom; num += 2)
            mark(l + (r-l) * num / denom, n - (step - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good way to transform the recursive in a non-recursive algorithm, that ask one of my problems. But I cannot find how to do now to draw. I have tried so:
for(i = 0; i<m-1; i++){
    printf(" ");
  }
    printf("|");

But when have I to add the \n and how to say my programm also to print the "|" above the other "|"?